# Asp.net LoginStatus - 'log out' shows but not logged in yet

Tags: asp.net

Why does my loginStatus show 'log out' even though I've not actually logged in yet?

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server"
LoginText="Log In"
LogoutText="Log Out"
LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx"
LogoutAction="Redirect" />
```

Comment: Log Out? Do you mean "Sign Out"?

Comment: ah wait, I see it, my autentication is set to 'windows'... duh!

Comment: you can answer your own question, and mark it as the correct answer. You get some reputation for that too

Answer (score 1):

Check authentication mode in web.config. It may be set to "Windows" change it to "Forms".